# Create Constraint only if not exists MySQL v5.7.12

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I want to create constraint in my table ONLY if it not exists. Is there any way to do it in MySQL? Below is the sample query which will return rows if constraint exists, want to execute ADD Constraint if not returning any rows. How can I possibly do it? Appreciate for any help.

`SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SAMPLE_TABLE'`

Comment: Write code to check the result of the query you show. Your code should conditionally add the constraint. If the constraint is already present, do not add the constraint.